CMake could not find GTest on Windows
I am building a Google Test project in Qt Creator using CMake. The library is located in C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0.
This is the auto-generated CMakeLists.txt file for the project:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(testProj LANGUAGES CXX)

enable_testing()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

if ($ENV{GOOGLETEST_DIR})
    get_filename_component(_GTEST_BASE $ENV{GOOGLETEST_DIR} REALPATH)
elseif (EXISTS "C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0") # set by QC
    get_filename_component(_GTEST_BASE "C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0" REALPATH) # set by QC
endif()

if (NOT GTEST_ROOT)
    if (_GTEST_BASE)
        message("Setting GTEST_ROOT to ${_GTEST_BASE}")
        set(GTEST_ROOT ${_GTEST_BASE})
    else()
        message("No GTEST_ROOT specified - using system defaults.")
    endif()
endif()

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
if (NOT GTest_FOUND)
    message (FATAL_ERROR "No GTest Found")
endif()

add_executable(testProj main.cpp tst_testproj.cpp)
add_test(NAME testProj COMMAND testProj)

target_link_libraries(testProj PRIVATE GTest::GTest)
if (GMock_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(testProj INTERFACE GTest::GMock)
endif()

When I run the above, I get the following error:
C:\Projects\testproj\CMakeLists.txt:25: error: Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR
GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)

Call stack:
  C:/Projects/testproj/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)
  C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindGTest.cmake:270 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message)

I have built the Google Test library in its directory, and I don't want to use the Git method of including it in the CMake config.
I've tried to use a lowercase gtest in find_package, and setting both GTest_ROOT and the (local) CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to the googletest directory, but they do not solve the issue.

Never use absolute paths in cmake. cmake should be able to find gtest automatically (when gtest ins properly installed) or based on relative path (when gtest is part of your repository). Looks like you need some package manager (conan/vcpkg/cpm) to properly address this issue.

find_package(GTest) locates GTest which is already built and installed. So, what exactly do you have under C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0? GTest installation? Or just GTest sources? Does you code actually set GTEST_ROOT variable? (Do not force us to guess which branch your code actually follows on your machine.)

@MarekR Do you mean the lines 'elseif (EXISTS "C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0")' and 'get_filename_component(_GTEST_BASE "C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0" REALPATH)'?
Qt Creator set those automatically - they don't seem to have an effect if removed (along with the rest of the lines from if ($ENV{GOOGLETEST_DIR}) to the second endif).

@Tsyvarev I ran cmake on the top-level CMakeLists in the googletest directory. It is only built; I am unsure of how to install CMake as the documentation uses the Git method.

"I ran cmake on the top-level CMakeLists in the googletest directory", "It is only built" - If you just run cmake .. then the project is not built, it is just configured. For build and install the project, you need to use build tool-specific commands: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md (look at sudo make install and near). Or run generic cmake --build and cmake --install <dir>.

@Tsyvarev And yes, it does set GTEST_ROOT if it's not already present.

Wow, what a doozy. Thanks Tsyvarev for the tips.
So, I deleted the following from the project's CMakeLists.txt:
if ($ENV{GOOGLETEST_DIR})
    get_filename_component(_GTEST_BASE $ENV{GOOGLETEST_DIR} REALPATH)
elseif (EXISTS "C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0") # set by QC
    get_filename_component(_GTEST_BASE "C:/cpplibraries/googletest-1.13.0" REALPATH) # set by QC
endif()

if (NOT GTEST_ROOT)
    if (_GTEST_BASE)
        message("Setting GTEST_ROOT to ${_GTEST_BASE}")
        set(GTEST_ROOT ${_GTEST_BASE})
    else()
        message("No GTEST_ROOT specified - using system defaults.")
    endif()
endif()

I went to the Google Test directory, and did what was written in the Google Test docs (mkdir build, cd build,  cmake ..).
In the 'build' folder, I opened the solution file in VS2019 (googletest-distribution.sln) with admin rights, then built every project for Debug (ALL_BUILD, gtest, gmock, gtest_main, gmock_main, INSTALL, RUN_TESTS, ZERO_CHECK) - it's unlikely that I had to build them all, but I wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything.
After doing the above, CMake had no more problems. Make sure both projects (google test's and the project using google test) have the same builds (debug w/ debug, release w/ release), and that they have the same runtime library setting (Google Test is a multithreaded static library/MTd_StaticDebug by default), or there'll be hell to pay in the form of linker errors (LNK2038/LNK2005).
Edit: Don't run cmake --install . before or after building in VS2019. Just the rest.

Rather than keeping Google Test locally on your machine, I would use FetchContent to get the right version of Google Test from the online repository.

That would be much less hassle, but unfortunately it is against my company's policy.
